# Why are 12 hour time values printing as date values with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, file-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, datetime

I have a field named `ORIGDTTIME` that contains 12 hour date values such as `06:36 AM`.  The field is a date  data type in my feature class, however when I print the values from this field I am not receiving any of the actual values that are in the feature class.  The date field is in a feature class in an Oracle SDE connection. The isue is reproduced in a file geodatabase

Here are the values that are being printed

```
[datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 13, 50), datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 13, 20), datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 13, 9), datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 13, 45), datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 14, 54), datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 10, 28, 19), datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 12, 48), datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 14, 48), None, datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 10, 36), datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 10, 27), datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 13, 46)].
```

I am using this script to print the values.

```
import arcpy
fldName = 'ORIGDTTIME'
fc = 'featureclass'
myList = set([row.getValue(fldName) for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)])
print myList
```

What should be changed to print the correct values in this script?

Comment: Where is your date field stored? i.e. where is your feature class stored?  If not in a file geodatabase, then when you copy this or a few features into a file geodatabase do you still see the same issue?  Whenever you can bring a geodatabase problem into a file geodatabase you widen the number of potential answerers greatly.

Comment: The date field is in a feature class in an Oracle SDE connection.  The isue is reproduced in a file geodatabase.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this. Its post manipulation though not sure how to get the right values to begin with.

```
import arcpy
import datetime
fldName = 'ORIGDTTIME'
fc = 'featureclass'
myList = set([(row.getValue(fldName).time()).strftime("%I:%M %p") for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(fc) if row])
print myList
```

Using test data

```
import datetime

list = [datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 13, 50), datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 13, 20), datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 13, 9), datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 13, 45), datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 14, 54), datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 10, 28, 19), datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 12, 48), datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 14, 48), None, datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 10, 36), datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 10, 27), datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 13, 46)]


dates = [(item.time()).strftime("%I:%M %p") for item in list if item]


for item in dates:
    print item
```

Returns

```
01:50 PM
01:20 PM
01:09 PM
01:45 PM
02:54 PM
10:28 AM
12:48 PM
02:48 PM
10:36 AM
10:27 AM
01:46 PM
```